# Excluding specific loggers using a rule in nlog programmatically

Tags: c#, nlog

I am looking at a way to implement the following logging rule programmatically.

```
<logger name="Name.Space.*" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Error" final="true" />
```

I can use the following to set the "*name*" & "*loglevel*" but there is no way to implement the final="true"..

```
LoggingRule fileLoggingRule = new LoggingRule("ConnDriverLogger", LogLevel.Trace, connDriverFileTarget);
connDriverLoggingConfig.LoggingRules.Add(fileLoggingRule);
```

Any suggestions to implement the above?

Answer (score 5):

What about the LoggingRule.Final property?

In your case:

```
LoggingRule fileLoggingRule = new LoggingRule("ConnDriverLogger", LogLevel.Trace, connDriverFileTarget);
fileLoggingRule.Final = true;
connDriverLoggingConfig.LoggingRules.Add(fileLoggingRule);
```

I found the LoggingRule.Final property here at NLog's repository:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/master/src/NLog/Config/LoggingRule.cs

Comment: No comment on the downvote?  Is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: No problem.  I made an edit to the answer (adding "at NLog's repository"), so you can try removing the vote if you would like.